# Multiple Records in sys.partition for a non-partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I was wondering why a non-partitioned table would have several orphaned records in sys.partitions.  Since it's a non-partitioned table, there should only be one record in sys.partitions and sys.dm_db_partition_stats.

Does anyone know if this is an issue and if so, how can I resolve it?

Thank you!

Edit:
The query is:

```
select * from sys.dm_db_partition_stats a right join sys.partitions b on a.partition_id = b.partition_id WHERE b.object_id = OBJECT_ID('tableA')
```

And the results are:

```
partition_id    partition_id    index_id    partition_number    hobt_id rows
72057602390818816   72057602390818816   5   1   72057602390818816   1844605
72057602776891392   NULL    1   1   72057602776891392   1842474
72057602776956928   NULL    1   1   72057602776956928   1842474
72057602777939968   NULL    1   1   72057602777939968   1842498
72057602778071040   NULL    1   1   72057602778071040   1842658
72057602782593024   NULL    6   1   72057602782593024   1842944
72057602783707136   72057602783707136   1   1   72057602783707136   1844605
72057602783772672   72057602783772672   6   1   72057602783772672   1844605
```

Yikes, is there a way to make it more readable?

Comment: Why are there many invalid rows with NULL values? Post clean data that can actually be read.

Comment: That's the issue.  In sys.partitions, there are several partition_ids for the one index_id/object_id and there's only one record in sys.dm_db_partition_stats.  I don't know how to clean up the sys.partitions table to get rid of the records that does not exist in sys.dm_db_partition_stats.

Comment: Find a way to provide query results that can be read. I refuse to find data by counting columns. Maybe reduce the number of columns and post an image.

Comment: Ah, sorry.  I edited the results.  Does that help?  I don't know how to align the columns though...

Comment: And I should explain that the first partition_id is from sys.partitions and the second partition_id is from sys.dm_db_partition_stats.

Comment: Much better. 5 rows for index_id 1. Same table, same index, same partition number but different hobts and different row counts(!). That does not look to good. Run DBCC CHECKDB and report back. Do these persist across instance restarts? I know that index builds (maybe online) do create duplication while the build is in progress.

Comment: I thought I could just drop and recreate the index to eliminate them...  I was doing index rebuilds and had to cancel out of them because I was blocking users so that must be why there are so many orphans.  I was able to complete the index rebuild = offline, but the orphans still exists.  DBCC CHECKDB will take a really long time and I have not restarted the instance.

Comment: Try CHECKTABLE. Or CHECKALLOC (which also does a CHECKCATALOG which is what I'm after). Don't just recreate the table. That would destroy the puzzle and would not be fun at all :)

Comment: Umm...  Wow...  I was just about to run another index rebuild = online, but just wanted to check the sys query one more time before I do it.  And what do you know...  It fixed itself!!  I'm so ecstatic, but extremely curious why it took so long to clean itself up.  

Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 2):

From the MSDN documentation [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175012.aspx):

> All tables and indexes in SQL Server contain at least one partition, whether or not they are explicitly partitioned.

The multiple rows probably correspond to your indexes, check the object_id and index_id and compare to sys.indexes.

Comment: Hm, perhaps I wasn't explaining the issue correctly.  I'll edit the above question.